# Problematic ‘go to comments’ emailed link from mentions

Tags: list, list-form, hyperlink, 2019, list-comments

We are having an odd issue with mentions/comments for a list we have in SharePoint 2019.

When a user does a mention and creates a comment it sends the email you would expect to the user with the ‘go to comment’ link, but recently it takes you to a classic view of the list item without the comment, which is also not allowing any sort of editing or interaction with the list item.

It is doing this for all users though including owners of the list.  This is happening now instead of opening up the modern view of the item they commented on. We have tried to adjust settings for users but that is not having an effect.

We also tested making a new list based on the established settings of this list and do not have this problem. Ideally we would like to keep the original list if possible without being required to transfer the data over to a new list. We are thinking it may be a user/group configuration issue. Has any one encountered this issue before? If so, were you able to resolve and how so?

Is there any additional I details that may be useful in resolving this issue?

Comment: What version of ShP are you using? Online, 2016, 2013?

Comment: @Martin Dub we are using 2019

Answer (score 1):

*Ideally we would like to keep the original list if possible without transferring data over.*

You can **duplicate** the whole list with or without the content in it, then delete the old list and replace it with the new, duplicated, list. Read [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-list-templates-c3884ad1-bc49-44b8-b3d6-3bc6a01eb393) on how to create list template, and create a new one from a template.